# JS array find values

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, filter

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему если добавить в поиск значения else то span не заполняется? Если оставить только if, то все работает.
Без else:

```js
var phones = [{
    "country": "UA",
    "code": "+380"
  },
  {
    "country": "RU",
    "code": "+7"
  },
  {
    "country": "MD",
    "code": "+373"
  }
];
$(".phone").keyup(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  phones.find(function(phones) {
    if (phones.code == val) {
      $("#county").text(phones.country);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="county"></span>
<input type="text" class="phone">
```

С else:

```js
var phones = [{
    "country": "UA",
    "code": "+380"
  },
  {
    "country": "RU",
    "code": "+7"
  },
  {
    "country": "MD",
    "code": "+373"
  }
];
$(".phone").keyup(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  phones.find(function(phones) {
    if (phones.code == val) {
      $("#county").text(phones.country);
    } else {
      $("#county").text("no");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="county"></span>
<input type="text" class="phone">
```

Comment: если нужно одно значение - используй [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Сейчас ты `filter` используешь как цикл. не надо так

Comment: Это неадекватное использование метода `filter` - в коде вопроса, коллбэк всегда возвращает `undefined`. Для простого перебора элементов массива используется метод `forEach` (или for-операторы).

Comment: @yar85, собственно тут и не важно что возвращает callback, потому что результат все равно не используется.

Comment: @Grundy, важно в контексте: см. начало предложения - "Это неадекватное использование метода `filter`". То есть, если не вырывать из контекста предложения ту фразу о возврате значения, все вполне связно и понятно (утверждение - и его обоснование). Подразумевалось что `filter` с коллбэком всегда возвращающим `undefined` неадекватен **всегда**, а не только тут.

Comment: Изменил поиск на find

Comment: @Grundy поменял код, посмотри.

Comment: @yar85 поменял код, посмотри.

Comment: @Vector, ты продолжаешь неправильно использовать функции. Посмотри внимательнее - они **возвращают значение**. А ты это значение не хочешь использовать.

Comment: @Vector, я согласен с Grundy, его вариант с `find` здесь удобнее всего (разве что я бы предложил повысить читаемость кода применив стрелочную функцию... но это уже дело вкуса, и по отношению к проблеме вообще незначительно).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном коде некорректно используется метод [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Данный метод предназначен для получения из коллекции элементов, удовлетворяющих условиям.

Поэтому передаваемый `callback` должен возвращать либо `true` либо `false`, чтобы можно было определить подходит элемент под условия или нет.

Метод `filter` всегда проходит по всем элементам, поэтому в случае с `else`, если нужный элемент не последний результатом всегда будет `no`.

Так как ищется всего один элемент, вместо `.filter` стоит воспользоваться методом [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
var el = phones.find(function(phone) {
    return (phone.code == val);
});
```

Здесь, в `el` будет либо найденный элемент либо `null`.

```js
var phones = [{
    "country": "UA",
    "code": "+380"
  },
  {
    "country": "RU",
    "code": "+7"
  },
  {
    "country": "MD",
    "code": "+373"
  }
];
$(".phone").keyup(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var el = phones.find(function(phone) {
    return (phone.code == val);
  });
  $("#county").text(el?.country ?? 'no');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="county"></span>
<input type="text" class="phone">
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без jQuery.

```js
var phones = [{
    "country": "UA",
    "code": "+380"
  },
  {
    "country": "RU",
    "code": "+7"
  },
  {
    "country": "MD",
    "code": "+373"
  }
];

document.querySelector('input.phone').addEventListener('keyup', e =>{
        document.querySelector('#country').textContent = 
            phones.find(el => el.code === e.target.value)?.country ?? 'no';
})
```

```html
<span id="country"></span>
<input type="text" class="phone">
```